How does an optical interrogator work?
Could someone explain the principles behind an optical interrogator?
I know that it is currently used to demodulate signals from FBG sensors, however, I am curious about the intrinsic workings and calculations behind the device. For example, what is the structure of the device? How does it demodulate the signals?
Thanks so much (I'm asking as none of my web searches have turned up anything except for ads for buying interrogators)!
P.S. If anyone could recommend a source or research article that goes in-depth about this topic, it would be much appreciated.
